# Merge several apps into one new

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ios-universal-app

I have an old app on app store that is divided into one free version for both iPhone and iPad and one paid version for both, so four different apps in total. I am going to make a complete new version of it so that it gets easier to handle. I want it, if possible, to be one universal app that maybe can use in-app purchase for customers to get the "premium" content.

However, people have paid for the previous version, is it possible to somehow let them have access to the premium content in the new one? 
Or do you think that it is better to make a complete new app with another name? :P
Any suggestions?

They can still use the old one if I remove it from app store right?

Comment: I guess you could make the previous paid version now free. And then if you know somehow that the user had the previous paid version, give him access to the premium content.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that you would need to discuss with Apple,  for the most part, they do not like it when potential sales could be lost.  After that is all said and done, there are ways for apps to share data with one another.

Have a look at this tutorial, it should give you an idea on how to do it.

http://www.enharmonichq.com/sharing-data-locally-between-ios-apps/